# Unable to run these two loops simultaneously

Tags: python, process

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

def func1():
    a=1
    while True:
        print("func1 up and running",a)
        a+=1
        sleep(1)


def func2():
    A=1
    while True:
        print("func2 up and running", A)
        A+=1
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    proc1 = Process(target=func1())
    proc1.start()

    proc2 = Process(target=func2())
    proc2.start()
```

It only runs func1 and not func2. I don't understand why it does this.

Answer (score 2):

In this call:

```
proc1 = Process(target=func1())
```

You are *calling `func1`*, rather than passing it as an argument to the `target` keyword option. Since you're calling `func1` here, and it never exits, this is effectively where your execution stops.

You want:

```
proc1 = Process(target=func1)
```

See the examples [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) for more details.